# Is the new Texas law on social media invalid on first amendment grounds?

Tags: us-constitution, texas, first-amendment

I have just seen [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39tAa-xEITg&lc=UgxjK8V4buN3gtUvfB54AaABAg.9SThM_M4NDy9SVs-xekVrZ) on Youtube:

"Republican Texas governor Greg Abbott has signed a law that forbids social media companies from banning people from their platforms based on their location and/or their politics. "

I presume this is intended to prevent things like Twitter banning Trump from posting.

Is this law unconstitutional, on the grounds that it violates freedom of the press?  As I understand it, the First Amendment means the government can't tell any publisher what political opinions they must  publish, or must not publish.  If that is correct, does 'the press' include social media?

Comment: Twitter didn't ban Trump for his politics, [they banned him for inciting violence](https://blog.twitter.com/en_us/topics/company/2020/suspension), which is in violation of their Terms & Services

Comment: If we treat them purely as private companies, then this might be seen as an attempt to make political orientation a protected class, but that still wouldn't allow someone to express those views on those platforms (although you may be able to make a case against that). The alternative is that they're trying to challenge the idea that they are private companies, instead of essential service providers, and free speech protection should extend to those platforms (to some degree). But that would need to be fought in the Supreme Court (and creating a law to start this process is not unheard of).

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Well, there are plenty of people with different politics that advocated for violence that didn't suffer any consequences despite being reported, so it's not that clear cut. If there's a rule that's only getting applied to one group of people and not another, it's not accurate to claim just the rule is the cause; it is also which group the person belongs to.

Comment: @ColleenV how many of them were addressing a crowd that later became a violent mob?

Comment: @Caleth I'm noting the argument, not arguing that any particular action was or was not warranted. The comment was a criticism of the question. My point is simply that criticism isn't as straightforward as it was stated.

Comment: The first amendment only says that the *government* can't restrict free speech.  Twitter is not the government, they can do whatever they want.

Comment: My question is not  about Twitter's actions.    My question is about the government's actions telling social media what to do.

Comment: I would like to see how government mandating how you use your intellectual property passes a SCOTUS test. This may very well have far reaching effects in regards to intellectual property rights.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman websites are non tangible property. They are intellectual property like a patent or a trade secret. People don't seem to understand that.

Comment: @NeilMeyer social media sites such as Facebook and Twitter are more than intellectual property.  They enjoy some protection under copyright and trademark law, and perhaps under some patents.  They are also mechanisms whereby people can publish information, and the government has a well established capacity to regulate such communications media.  For example, they are "interactive computer services" under section 230.  The government has chosen to absolve such services of liability for content supplied by users, but it didn't have to.

Comment: "Republican Texas governor Greg Abbott has signed a law that forbids social media companies from banning people from their platforms based on their location" If social media sites ban all Texans, I'm not sure Texas would have any jurisdiction.

Comment: Related for Florida? [Will Florida Social Media Bill Allow Trump back Online?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/64706/2618).

Comment: This might be a separate question, but why does Governor Abbott think that companies such as Facebook and Twitter fall within his jurisdiction?

Comment: @AndrewT. That bill was put out of enforcement by the Florida federal circuit.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## most likely

The government can't compel people to some sort of speech under the 1st amendment. Forcing a company to **host** people is compelled speech by the company.

It is well established that the government can't compel a newspaper to host its messages as it wants. The key case might be [Miami Herald Publishing Co. v. Tornillo 418 US 241 (1974)](https://www.oyez.org/cases/1973/73-797). In this case, it was deemed unconstitutional that *a newspaper would need to host speech* of a political candidate the newspaper didn't like in the same amount it had used to disparage that candidate.

While the Miami Herald brought the newspaper into the line by the action of the newspaper, [Wooley v. Maynard 430 U.S. 705 (1977)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/430/705/) held that the state could not force *any* citizen to host its motto. Or for the matter, **any** message.

> The State may not constitutionally require an individual to participate in the dissemination of an ideological message by displaying it on his private property in a manner and for the express purpose that it be observed and read by the public. Pp. 71717.

Forcing a public web page to host advertisement or speech from any government - or under the threat of the government action - is compelled speech and violates the rulings of Miami Herald, Wooley and other cases.

However, there is a little light for the government under PruneYard, Turner Broadcasting and Rumsfeld. However, all of them don't cut here: Turner Broadcasting was about a service provider for radio that did not host its own speech. PruneYard is a shopping center that doesn't host its own speech and is only useful in California as there is a California constitution issue. And Rumsfeld dealt with military recruitment, which always is special.

[A similar Florida law was deemed to be very likely unconstitutional by the (federal) Northern District of Florida](https://usatoday.com/story/tech/2021/06/30/florida-trump-facebook-youtube-social-media-law-judge-blocks/7820915002/) ([Injunction Text](https://netchoice.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/NetChoice-v.-Moody-PI-decision.pdf))

### Addendum

[A joint lawsuit by NetChoice & CCIA was filed against Texas on 22nd September 2021](https://netchoice.org/media-press/netchoice-and-ccia-sue-state-of-texas-for-legislation-hb-20-that-flagrantly-violates-texan-free-speech/) ([Complaint](https://netchoice.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/1-main.pdf)), asking for a [preliminary injunction](https://netchoice.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/22_Plaintiffs-Motion-for-Preliminary-Injunction.pdf). NetChoice puts its filings on [their website](https://netchoice.org/netchoice-and-ccia-v-paxton-resource-page/).

### Further reading:

- [Ken White - Make No Law podcast #11: Deplatformed](https://legaltalknetwork.com/podcasts/make-no-law/2019/08/deplatformed-social-media-censorship-and-the-first-amendment/)
- [Ken White - Section 230 Is The Subject of The Most Effective Legal Propaganda I've Ever Seen](https://popehat.substack.com/p/section-230-is-the-subject-of-the)

### 01st December 2021 Update

Indeed, the relevant parts of HB20 were put out of enforcement [via  injunction](https://netchoice.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/51.-ORDER.pdf) on December 1st, 2021, reasoning that:

> Social media platforms have a First Amendment right to moderate content disseminated on
> their platforms. See Manhattan Cmty. Access Corp. v. Halleck, 139 S. Ct. 1921, 1932 (2019) (recognizing
> that “certain private entities[] have rights to exercise editorial control over speech and speakers on
> their properties or platforms”). Three Supreme Court cases provide guidance. First in *Tornillo*, the
> Court struck down a Florida statute that required newspapers to print a candidate’s reply if a
> 13
> newspaper assailed her character or official record, a “right of reply” statute. 418 U.S. at 243.
>
> [...]
>
> In *Hurley v. Irish-Am. Gay, Lesbian & Bisexual Grp. of Bos.*, the Supreme Court held that a
> private parade association had the right to exclude a gay rights group from having their own float in
> their planned parade without being compelled by a state statute to do otherwise. *515 U.S. 557, 572–
> 73 (1995)*.
>
> [...]
>
> Finally, the Supreme Court ruled that California could not require a private utility company
> to include a third party’s newsletters when it sent bills to customers in *Pac. Gas & Elec. Co. v. Pub.
> Utilities Comm’n of California, 475 U.S. 1, 20–21 (1986)*.

> HB 20 compels social media platforms to
> significantly alter and distort their products. Moreover, “the targets of the statutes at issue are the
> editorial judgments themselves” and the “announced purpose of balancing the discussion—reining
> in the ideology of the large social-media providers—is precisely the kind of state action held
> unconstitutional in Tornillo, Hurley, and PG&E.” Id. HB 20 also impermissibly burdens social media
> platforms’ own speech. Id. at *9 (“[T]he statutes compel the platforms to change their own speech in
> other respects, including, for example, by dictating how the platforms may arrange speech on their
> sites.”). For example, if a platform appends its own speech to label a post as misinformation, the
> platform may be discriminating against that user’s viewpoint by adding its own disclaimer. HB 20
> restricts social media platforms’ First Amendment right to engage in expression when they disagree
> with or object to content.

> For these reasons, IT IS ORDERED that the State’ s motion to dismiss, (Dkt. 23), is
> DENIED.
>
> IT IS FURTHER ORDERED that Plaintiffs’ motion for preliminary injunction, (Dkt.
> 12), is GRANTED. Until the Court enters judgment in this case, the Texas Attorney General is
> ENJOINED from enforcing Section 2 and Section 7 of HB 20 against Plaintiffs and their
> members. Pursuant to Federal Rule of Civil Procedure 65(c), Plaintiffs are required to post a
> $1,000.00 bond.
>
> IT IS FINALLY ORDERED that Plaintiffs’ motion to strike, (Dkt. 43), is DISMISSED
> WITHOUT PREJUDICE AS MOOT.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129919/discussion-on-answer-by-trish-is-the-new-texas-law-on-social-media-invalid-on-fi).

Answer (score 18):

That will be determined later by the courts. You might think so, if Facebook etc. were strictly private platforms. [Knight First Amdt. Inst. at  Columbia  Univ. v. Trump](https://casetext.com/case/knight-first-amendment-inst-at-columbia-univ-v-trump-1), 928 F. 3d 226 somewhat undermines that thinking. The court disallowed Trump from exercising ordinary First Amendment control over his account. In reviewing the lower court finding,

> After concluding that the defendants had created a public forum in the
> interactive space of the Account, the court concluded that, by
> blocking the Individual Plaintiffs because of their expressed
> political views, the government had engaged in viewpoint
> discrimination.

The appeals court said that

> we agree that in blocking the Individual Plaintiffs the President
> engaged in prohibited viewpoint discrimination

The court rejected the contention that

> the Account is exclusively a vehicle for his own speech to which the
> Individual Plaintiffs have no right of access and to which the First
> Amendment does not apply.

An analogous law was passed in [Florida](https://www.flsenate.gov/Session/Bill/2021/7072). There was a lawsuit and [enforcement was stayed](https://netchoice.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Order-Granting-Stay.pdf), which means that the court found that the arguments against the law were likely to prevail. The answer w.r.t. [the Texas law](https://legiscan.com/TX/text/HB20/2021/X2) hinges on the difference between the Florida vs Texas laws, and the basis for the injunction against the Florida law.

Comment: Knight Institute however was mooted and voided.

Comment: Yes, for the reason that Trump is no longer president. The reasoning in the ruling was not touched.

Comment: It seems that this would be far closer to the Florida case than to *Knight Institute*. That result was predicated on the finding that Trump's Twitter account was a mechanism for government communication. Because there is no such claim as to the social media companies more broadly, there's not much force to the argument that they should be stripped of their First Amendment protections.

Comment: _Knight_ argued that Trump created a public forum on his personal Twitter account. While the public forum existed, it was impermissible for the government (including the President) to deny access to that forum because of protected political speech. However, _Knight_ did not rule that Twitter was _in general_ a public forum, just Trump's account.

Comment: Hard agree with what @AndrewRay said, and more importantly, Knight did not even decide that Twitter can't ban people from viewing Trump's account on the basis of their political opinion, it decided that *Trump* can't do that. That entire case hinged on the critical detail that Trump is a government official making use Twitter as a part of his job in office, and this does not apply here in general.

Comment: @DreamConspiracy more precisely, _Knight_ holds that _the President of the United States_ is constrained by the reasoning we're discussing, which is why the case was dismissed when Trump ceased to be President of the United States.  As you note, it's not about creating a "public forum," which Twitter is in general, but about the use of Twitter for official government purposes.

Comment: @AndrewRay: Indeed, Twitter *actually did* deny some people (in fact, everyone) access to Trump's Twitter account after the events of January 6, 2021. Obviously the court did not prohibit them from doing that.

Comment: Are you sure that enforcement of the Florida law being stayed means that the court judged the plaintiffs *likely* to prevail?  Wouldn't it be enough for the court to decide (1) that there is a genuine controversy, and (2) that the plaintiffs would suffer irreparable harm if the state proceeded with enforcement while that controversy was being adjudicated?

Comment: @JohnBollinger "To get a preliminary injunction, a party must show that they will suffer irreparable harm unless the injunction is issued. Preliminary injunctions may only be issued after a hearing. When determining whether to grant preliminary injunctions, judges consider the extent of the irreparable harm, each party's likelihood of prevailing at trial, and any other public or private interests implicated by the injunction. Parties may appeal the judge's decisions on whether to award a preliminary injunction." https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/preliminary_injunction

Comment: @JohnBollinger From the Florida court itself: **“The plaintiffs are likely to prevail on the merits of their claim that these statutes violate the First Amendment. There is nothing that could be severed and survive.”**

Comment: That's useful @Trish, but it speaks to the specifics of this case.  The answer says "enforcement was stayed, which means that [...]", and in my understanding, the fact that enforcement of a law was stayed in a situation like this does not mean or require the court to take such a strong position on the likely disposition of the case.

Answer (score 11):

No one knows how the courts will eventually rule on this law, or on the somewhat similar Florida law now being litigated.

It is true, as the answer by Trish says, that the government cannot compel a publisher to publish things against its wishes, and that an individual cannot generally be compelled to make statements of political views. In [*West Virginia State Board of Education v. Barnette*, 319 U.S. 624 (1943)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Virginia_State_Board_of_Education_v._Barnette) the US Supreme Court wrote:

> If there is any fixed star in our constitutional constellation, it is that no official, high or petty, can prescribe what shall be orthodox in politics, nationalism, religion, or other matters of opinion or force citizens to confess by word or act their faith therein.

However [Section 230(c)(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_230) of the  Communications Decency Act says that:

> No provider or user of an interactive computer service shall be treated as the publisher or speaker of any information provided by another information content provider.

Thus requiring that a person be allowed to have an account is not requiring the owner of the service to **publish** anything, since the owner is not the publisher of any user's content, nor does it require the owner or anyone else to make any statement, and in particular not to make any statement specified by the government.

It is constitutional, in general, for a state to pass anti-discrimination laws, or laws requiring that a business give access to particular groups of people. If a social media platform is treated as a service allowing people to publish their own views, then the state may pass laws limiting the exclusion of people from that service on particular grounds.

That does not prove that the law is constitutional, but it shifts the ground of inquiry significantly. The exact provisions of the Texas and Florida laws may be significant in the eventual decision.

I doubt that *Knight Institute.* will be found relevant. That case was based on the very unusual situation that a public official, and in particular the president of the United States, was using social media as a means for distributing official policy statements, and as a public forum for comments on them, and it was held that Trump could not, in those circumstances, exclude specific individuals, as that would constitute government action against those people. That situation is quite different from the ones under the Texas and Florida social media laws.

Comment: Miami HErad and Wooly v Meynard as well, but to a lesser degree.

Comment: I have always thought that Section 230c companies enjoying special protections as "not publishers" while simultaneously censoring information based on the opinion of the company is strange. You can't have your cake and eat it too (well, anywhere other than under the law I guess ;))

Comment: @ColleenV If they were liable for content, almost everything controversial would be blocked or removed. If they couldn't moderate protected speech, you'd very quickly have e.g. pornographic political memes all over.

Comment: Sure, @Caleth, but when section 230 was first enacted, the problem it addressed was that information service providers couldn't effectively filter content while still providing service at all.  The implied *quid pro quo* was that in exchange for providing a useful service *that was understood not to be filtered*, information service providers were excused from responsibility for the content of the speech they conveyed.  Now that providers have taken to exercising effective editorial control over the speech they convey, the premises of section 230 have been undermined.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't remember it ever being assumed that content wouldn't be filtered. Human moderation and blacklisting profanity predates that legislation

Comment: @Caleth Although the things that social media companies do block (not ban; accounts are not banned for this content AFAIK but the content itself is blocked) are generally egregious in nature, such as graphic videos of death, graphic sexuality, and so on.  No matter how much you do or don't like Trump's tweets, you'd be hard pressed to equate them to something like that.

Comment: @John Bollinger I do not think there was any provision or understanding that online services be completely unfiltered, and to the best of my knowledge none of the major ones ever were. Rather the issue was the reverse: Prior to sec 230, doing any content moderation might impose liability for the content on the service. One purpose of sec 230 was to allow a service to do some content moderation without assuming responsibility for things that slipped by. Can you cite any source for the idea that sec 230 was based on the understanding that content was to be un-filtered?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Your interpretation frankly makes no sense. Under *Cubby v. CompuServe* and *Stratton Oakmont v. Prodigy Services*, what you describe was already the law before section 230 had been enacted (i.e. you're excused from liability as long as you don't filter anything). Congress enacted section 230 as part of the Communications Decency Act, which was specifically intended to clean up the internet and reduce the amount of "obscene" content on it. They wanted more filtering, not less.

Comment: @ColleenV Punishing entities for not helping people spread lies would also be rather strange. It would create a perverse incentive for entities to not remove *any* libelous materiel, because once they do, they become a "publisher", and have to remove *all* libelous materiel, even material they aren't aware is libelous. If you kick someone out of your house because they're spouting lies, are you now a "publisher" and liable for anything one of your guests says?

Comment: @Acccumulation It’s strange when folks pretend a $48B company that serves millions of people is somehow akin to an individual in their living room. If the public isn’t getting the benefit of more speech, why should we give them extra protection from the law? The intent of 230c was not to give corporations free reign to suppress any speech they disliked without consequences. If corps are going to start picking and choosing which speech is harmful to the public, the public needs the recourse of the courts.

Comment: The consequence of removing 230c protections would be that the SM corps would have to apply their rules more consistently or not at all. I'm not sure why everyone jumps to the "not at all" option when we live in the age of the computer algorithm that can analyze our posts in real time to serve us ads. We have far more capability to identify and remove unlawful speech than we imagined was possible in 1995.

Comment: @ColleenV yes we do, but IMO as a software developer, we do not yet have any program which can reliably do so to a standard that a court would approve.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I don't want to completely derail your answer, but I think that there is plenty of protection in the US legal system to keep companies from being held civilly liable for impossible standards. The billion $ corp does have a big advantage in court. Maybe I'm just old and have more faith in the US legal system. It's far from perfect, but it works pretty well. Corps should be allowed to set terms of use for their products, but they shouldn't be protected from liability once they've attained the sort of power the mega tech corps currently  wield.

Comment: I don't think you are coming anywhere close to 'derailing" y answer. What rights and powers a corp that runs an SM service **should** have is a policy decision, and so not really on-topic her on LAW. The standards that were being imposed on moderation prior to Sec 230 are not currently attainable by purely automated processes; indeed I think they would require fully sapient human-level decision makers for final review. Whether to change those standards and if so how, or to grant immunity, or take some other action is again a policy decision, Any of those routes could be enacted law.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I meant "derailing the discussion under your answer"... I know it's annoying sometimes to get pinged by a discussion that's not really relevant to the answer.

Comment: No problem. It is an interesting discussion eve if a bit aside from the question. I think you are expectign morfe of automated processes than thy can manage. Such things can help, but IMO humans are needed in the loop if effective moderation to the level of eliminating actionable defamation and other problematic posts is to be achieved, and that is not free.

Comment: I guess my feeling is that whatever method of moderation the company chooses only needs to be good enough to prevent most cases from being brought, not perfect. The company can decide what legal exposure they can abide. I'm against "corporate welfare" type laws on principle. Either the company should enjoy protection and be more hands off, or forgo protection and have complete control.

Comment: I also find that technology needs challenges to overcome. Maybe the only reason we don't have good automated moderation is because we've never really needed it.

Comment: We do need challenges, but this one is being worked on. Thew firm I work for is putting sizable resources behind so-called "natural language processing" (NLP) not to moderate social media, but to urn dictated notes from a doctor working on a case into useful medical codes and notes in standard formats. This work could also be applied to moderation. That is one way I know how hard a job designing such a program would be. (I also have a decades-long interst in AI.) NLP is being worked on for other purposes as well.

Comment: Undoubtedly there are many technologies being actively developed that might be useful for moderation. However we will probably see huge strides forward if something happens like FaceBook being unable to find enough human moderators to wade through the horrific posts they have to deal with, and not taking those down quickly enough could end up costing the company enough to worry them.

Answer (score -2):

The Knight ruling does not address the rights of the company owning the platform and their ability to set rules, regulations, and policies on their services.  Each PERSON may have rights but they quickly diminish if he/she violates terms of service.  The idea they are of a public forum will not stand up over long term scrutiny.  No way.  People think the idea of free speech is sacred, and it is, but free enterprise reigns supreme and nobody is going tell a private company how it should regular it's own IP.  That's far more dangerous than any bogus free speech argument here, of which there is none.

Comment: There are already laws which regulate what  company can do with its IP. I think you are correct that the *Knight* case will not apply, but that does not settle the issue at all. Can you site any source or case for  "The idea they are of a public forum will not stand up ..." please?